# AWS S3 browser upload prevent signature hijacking

Tags: amazon-web-services

I followed [this](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) article on how to upload image directly from browser to AWS S3 server.

When testing the implementation for Ruby, I realized that the signature in the HTML form input still remains the same from one request to another.

```
require 'base64'
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'

policy_document = 'sample policy_document'
aws_secret_key = 'sample aws_secret_key'

policy = Base64.encode64(policy_document).gsub("\n","")

signature = Base64.encode64(
    OpenSSL::HMAC.digest(
        OpenSSL::Digest::Digest.new('sha1'), 
        aws_secret_key, policy)
    ).gsub("\n","")

puts policy
puts signature
```

If it's not unique, how could we prevent user from hijacking our AWS S3 server by arbitrarily upload images from terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that the signature is the same is because what is signed is the policy document. The policy can be as detailed as you like (for example, you can specify that only objects with a certain prefix can be written, objects within a size range, etc) If you use the same policy every time, you get the same signature.

It's a good idea to think hard about the policy and crank it down as tightly as you can. For example, if you only want pepole to upload images, constrain the content-type to a short list of image types.

There are some more examples of POST policies here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/HTTPPOSTExamples.html

There are a couple of ways you can limit the potential for abuse for a given signed policy. One way is to generate and sign new policy for every upload which has an expiration date not too far in the future. After that date, S3 will refuse POSTs with that signed policy. You can also make the signature unique per upload by generating a randomized nonce, and require through the policy that the nonce be included in the metadata. So your policy would include

```
["x-amz-meta-uuid", "14365123651274"]
```

Then you would add a field to your POST (This is the second example on the page I linked above).

```
--TheMultipartForm-DataBoundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="x-amz-meta-uuid"

14365123651274
```